# how publish java webapp on vps server, i tried by it doesn't work

Tags: java, ubuntu, hosting, vps

I want deploy java webapp on vps server with ubuntu. I installed jdk, jre and tomcat, but when i try to see tomcat standard welcome page it returns error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP. Here is the link to my server: http://something.nazwa.pl:8080.
How can i repair this error and how properly prepare  vps to java application?
I had never been using Linux,so it is difficult to me.

Comment: What are your version of JDK and Tomcat?

Comment: I installed Tomcat9 and default open jdk it returns 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode) after command java -version

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Try to set the [JDK 8 of oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) or OpenJDK 8. Becasue from the Site of [Apache Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/building.html)

> Building Apache Tomcat requires a JDK (version 8) to be installed. You
>   can download one from
>   And you jave OpenJDK 9

And remember

> IMPORTANT: Set an environment variable JAVA_HOME to the pathname of
>   the directory into which you installed the JDK release.

--- Edit ---
Ok going more deeper I found that tomcat 9 can run in Open JDK 9, but it might contains bugs

> For example, users were successfully running Tomcat 8 on Java 8 many
>   months before the first stable Java 8 release. However, users of early
>   access builds should be aware of the following:
>
> It is not unusual for the initial early access builds to contain bugs
>   that can cause problems for web applications running on Tomcat. If the
>   new Java version introduces new language features then the default JSP
>   compiler may not support them immediately. Switching the JSP compiler
>   to javac may enable these new language features to be used in JSPs. If
>   you do discover an problem using a Java early access build, please ask
>   for help. The Tomcat user's mailing list is probably the best place to
>   start.

From [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

Conclusion

Try to go with JDK 8 of oracle and set your enviorement variable

Comment: Thank you, I installed jdk 8 and tomcat 8 and everything works well.